# How to Load tinyUrl in glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm trying to load the tinyUrl into an ImageView using Glide. below is the mentioned URL.

```
String imageUrl = "http://hck.re/3Cm0IX";

Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .into(imageView);
```

apparently this isn't working.

Comment: Make sure you have added `Internet permission` in the manifest

Comment: Does it work when you use `"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/aik_alif4181734.jpg"` as an url?

Comment: I checked & your short url is working fine. Maybe it's a internet connection or Internet permission is missing in the manifest  issue

Comment: I'm getting the short link from server. and it's working fine when i use "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/aik_alif4181734.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `imageUrl` with the following :

```
  String imageUrl = "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/he-public-data/aik_alif4181734.jpg" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using the below URL

https://mindorks.com/android/store/Image-Loaders/aminography/redirectglide